# Jenkins - Visual Studio Command line arguments

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, ssis, sql-server-2012

Planning to Build & Deploy SSIS Projects(ISPAC) or Database Solutions (DAPAC) from Jenkins using Visual Studio Command line arguments.

Question: I know i can execute Windows batch commands but i would like to if i can execute Visual Studio Commands as well.

FYI: Planning to install Visual Studio on the Agent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be able to do it using [msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild). If your SSIS solution can be compiled by Visual Studio, the msbuild command can do it as well (See also [msbuild integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2015)).

To utilize msbuild to create an ispac/dapac file take a look at [this article](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/). It's not Jenkins specific but that should not matter.